# libPAM library Authentication failure after enabling pam_google_authenticator

Tags: pam

I've enabled the following line in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

With the nullok option, it should not ask OTP when it is not set up (e.g.: when no .google_authenticator file is present in the home-folder).

I have some users, **whom do not have a home folder** (I use the PAM system to verify the password of that user, nothing more)

Tested via the following library: https://github.com/FirefighterBlu3/python-pam

```
python3 pam.py 
Username: ...
Password: ...
Auth result: Authentication failure (7)
```

When I disable `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok`, the authentication is OK:

```
python3 pam.py 
Username: ...
Password: ...
Auth result: Success (0)
```

How can I check the passwords of users without a home-folder when the google_authenticator is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is all over the place; `open_secret_file` simply sets a
`SECRETNOTFOUND` flag if `nullok` is set and the `open` fails, as it
should for users who lack a home directory. Setting `debug` for a better
trace might help show exactly what log messages result and from there
you might get a better idea of exactly where is code is going.

Meanwhile, `open_secret_file` is only called if `secret_filename`
is non-`NULL`, and if so we may need to know what `buf` is (which
is used in various places, and is sometimes allocated, or sometimes
a `buf[1000]`, yuck) to know whether the `stopped_by_rate_limit`
thing happens.

Anyways, `get_secret_filename` indicates that the default location of
the secret file could be changed to somewhere that is not the home
directory. And what exactly does your "whom do not have a home folder"
mean? Because if that field is empty then one of

```
if (!pw->pw_dir) {
  log_message(LOG_ERR, pamh, "user(\"%s\") has no home dir", username);
  goto errout;
}

if (*pw->pw_dir != '/') {
  log_message(LOG_ERR, pamh, "User \"%s\" home dir not absolute", username);
  goto errout;
}
```

will match (this is where adding that `debug` PAM flag might help) which
means `get_secret_filename` returns `NULL` which means `if (secret_filename) {` fails which means the `SECRETNOTFOUND` flag cannot
be set as `open_secret_file` is never called. Then a lot of code
follows, but I'm going to guess that it will fail as you observe
(`debug` might tell you more here).

Several different options to fix this situation suggest themselves.

### Patch the Code

So, one fix might be to patch `get_secret_filename` to set

```
params->nullok = SECRETNOTFOUND;
```

when a home directory does not exist (in various places), or maybe to
set `params->nullok = SECRETNOTFOUND` by default but to turn if off when
`get_secret_filename` returns something that is not `NULL`. Plus an
audit of the logic to help ensure that you are not somehow creating a
security vulnerability here.

### Give the Users an Empty Home Directory They Cannot Write To

A simpler option might be to use `/var/empty` or something for the home
directory for these users, in which case the `SECRETNOTFOUND` flag will
probabaly get set correctly. (And you may want to audit that nothing
does get added to `/var/empty` and certainly those users must not have
permission to change that directory.)

### PAM Complications

Linux PAM lets you skip subsequent rules, so maybe there's a PAM module
that if the home directory is empty (or so forth) the result of that is
to skip over the subsequent `pam_google_authenticator.so` rule.

(I'd probably give the users a home directory they cannot write to.)